# Unable to SSH to one server but able to ssh to amazon ec2

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am behind a firewall which restricts access to Internet and the only way we are allowed to access the Internet is via a proxy service via port 8080.
Now, I am using corkscrew and it is allowing me to tunnel to the Amazon EC2 via SSH and using the corkscrew but I am not able to tunnel to the DigitalOcean's server whereas from a non restrictive Internet I am able to access both of the servers. Can anyone help me in solving this?

Here is the log when ssh is running via the `-v` command :-

```
ssh -vvv XXXX@XXXXX -p 443
OpenSSH_6.5, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 49: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for 128.199.203.97
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec corkscrew proxy.ac.in 8080 1.199.203.97 443 /bin/.corkscrew-auth
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1001
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/Blueelvis_RoXXX/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/Blueelvis_RoXXX/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/Blueelvis_RoXXX/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Blueelvis_RoXXX/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Blueelvis_RoXXX/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Blueelvis_RoXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Blueelvis_RoXXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Blueelvis_RoXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Blueelvis_RoXXX/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.5
Proxy could not open connnection to 1.99.203.97:  Proxy Authentication Required
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

On connecting to the Amazon EC2 via the same parameters, I am able to tunnel through it but not on this one. I do not get any Proxy Authentication Error Required when connecting to the Amazon Instance but I do get the error when I am connecting to the DigitalOcean server. Any idea what is happening and why?

**I am running CYGWIN on Windows**

Comment: You need to post more information. Your comments are hard to read.

Comment: @Peter - What kind of more information do you need? Let me know and I ll post it. I have edited the question again btw.

Comment: "Proxy could not open connnection to 1.99.203.97:  Proxy Authentication Required" looks to be the cause of the problem, regardless.

Comment: @Peter - The IP has been modified for privacy reasons mate :P . Anyways I figured the solution of connecting to the DigitalOcean Server.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the IP is. The message blatantly says it is a problem with proxy auth to whatever hop that is.

Comment: @Peter - I already posted the solution to this one. Dunno why, with amazon server it requires no authentication whereas for the digital ocean it requires the authentication. Rest Steps are detailed in the asnwer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was solved by using a program named CNTLM. The program can be downloaded here

http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/

1. Download and install the program.
2. Configure the `INI` file to your desired proxy settings and make sure that the line in which the listen address, does not start with `#`.
3. Start the CNTLM software.
4. Edit your ssh_config file ProxyCommand /bin/corkscrew.exe `127.0.0.1 3128` %h %p. Where corkscrew is the program used and `127.0.0.1` is the listen address configured in CNTLM and `3128` is the port on which CNTLM listens of the address.

Following the steps immediately gave me a connection to Digital Ocean's Server.